# How to build a barcode reader in js with camera?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications, camera

Im a beginer in js and jquery that's why i need your help . I would like to build a barcode reader in js thanks to the camera on my phone . 
For the moment i do this :

```js
  <video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
    <button id="snap">Snap Photo</button>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
     var video = document.getElementById('video');

     // Get access to the camera!
     if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
       // Not adding `{ audio: true }` since we only want video now
     navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
      video.play();
  });
  // Elements for taking the snapshot
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var video = document.getElementById('video');

  // Trigger photo take
  document.getElementById("scan").addEventListener("click", function() {
 context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
  });
}
```

but it doesn't work so im pretty lost x) 
thank you in advance to your help ! (sorry for my english :D)

Comment: I think it is useful to you  `https://atandrastoth.co.uk/main/pages/plugins/codereader/`

Comment: Thank you I will look at this !

Answer (score 1):

Why not using some libs, eg.

- [QuaggaJS](https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/)
- [Some other reader](https://github.com/tonylampada/barcodescanner/tree/gh-pages)

Comment: hi true_glerI am testing the service but it shows the following error: sw.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: workbox.expiration.Plugin is not a constructor 
serviceWorker.js:97 Error during service worker registration: TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://qr.maslick.tech/') with script ('https://qr.maslick.tech/sw.js'): ServiceWorker script evaluation failed
Promise.catch (async)
(anonymous) @ serviceWorker.js:51
load (async)
(anonymous) @ serviceWorker.js:34
(anonymous) @ main.76916fec.chunk.js:1
barcode.js:9 Barcode scanner initialized

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the [zbar](https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar) C/C++ library and transpile it to [WebAssembly](https://webassembly.org/) (which is supported by all major browsers) using [Emscripten](https://emscripten.org/).

> Emscripten is an LLVM/Clang-based compiler that compiles C and C++ source code to WebAssembly, primarily for execution in web browsers.

Here's an example app I have just published:

- https://github.com/maslick/koder
- https://qr.maslick.tech